# How do i seperate multiple list values with a square and remove button (like the hotmail "To" field - jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

In hotmail when you type in multiple emails it kind of puts a square around the email and adds a remove "X"  you also see this in facebook when your creating facebook ads and are adding categories.  Is this jquery? What's this functionality even called?  Tutorial anywhere?

Thx.

Comment: jQuery is just a JavaScript library. What you see on hotmail / facebook is either plain JS or perhaps they also use some JS library.

Answer (score 0):

The square is a border. The "x" is just a little graphic which is revealed at the same time as the border, when you hover the email. In jQuery you would do something like this:

```
$("#emailTable tr").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("border");
    $(this).find(".deleteButton").show();
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("border");
    $(this).find(".deleteButton").hide();
});
```

[**Ugly example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/F3wub/)

Answer (score 0):

Those are usually called "tokens", here's the first jquery library I found on google searching for **jquery tokens**: http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/